# mysql set one item id to the auto_increment max id

Tags: mysql

for example,there are several items in a table

```
 id |name|info
 1  |Jim |Male
 2  |Rob |Male
```

the id of the table is auto_increment, and now i want to update Jim's row to the bottom of Rob ,and get the newest id, aka

```
 id |name|info
 2  |Rob |Male
 3  |Jim |Male
```

and get the id of (3), what's the sql expression?

Comment: That sounds as if you want to use the id for some purpose _other than just identifying a record_, like for sorting. Don't do that. It's not the job of an id.

Answer (score 4):

Since you can't select the max(id) in a the same update query, you have to define the max(id) as a variable. The query you need :

```
SET @max = (SELECT max(`id`) FROM `table` FOR UPDATE);
UPDATE `table` SET `id` = @max+1 WHERE `name` = "Jim";
```

***EDIT*** : You are not supposed to update an id since it's an unique identifier. If you want to use sorting methods, you should add an integer column "position".

Comment: You might want to add `FOR UPDATE` to the 1-st query. Just in case someone sneaks in and inserts another record before the update. Also don't mess with the autoincrements unless you really really have to, it will bite you later.

Comment: @Vatev : sure ! I didn't focus on security purposes, but i edit my answer to include it.

Comment: the row is auto_increment,and after i`ve update the id, how can i let the auto_increment move on?otherwise the id will be duplicated after i insert a new one.

Comment: You have to `ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = max(id) ...` and it becomes a real mess. That's why you shouldn't update an id column !

Comment: that"s because some old data in our db has been polluted , and we have to move them to new place and not change the structure of the table;

Answer (score 1):

there is no update for autoincrement column you could delete Jims row and then insert it again and it will be id = 3

```
 DELETE FROM `table` where id = 1
```

then

```
 INSERT INTO `table` (name , info) VALUES ('jim' , 'male')
```